# Not accessible because it is Friend in Generics

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, generics

I'm trying to get a generic method working in VB.NET but I can't get the signature to accept a generic type parameter. I just get "'t' is not accesble because it is "Friend"".

My method signature is:

```
Public Shared Function GetOffset(ByVal coll As IEnumerable(Of t), ByVal offset As Integer, ByVal limit As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a type parameter as far as I've seen. Shouldn't it be:

```
Public Shared Function GetOffset(Of t)(ByVal coll As IEnumerable(Of t), _
     ByVal offset As Integer, ByVal limit As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of t)
```

Note that conventionally this would be `T` rather than `t`.

Comment: Thank you. VB.NET seems a lot more verbose than C# in that I have to declare that type param three times.

Comment: @Echilon: No, you're only *declaring* the type parameter once - you're then *using* the type parameter twice more... just as you would in C#: `public static IEnumerable<T> GetOffset<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, int offset, int limit)` - you'll see that `<T>` still appears three times.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class named t in another assembly? Friend means it will only be accessible in that assembly. Consider making it public. Then it is accessible to other assemblies as well.

Public: accessible to all assemblies that reference this assembly.
Protected: accessible to all classes that inherit from this class.
Friend: accessible to all classes in the same assembly.
Private: accessible to this class only.
Protected Friend: accessible to all classes in this assembly, that also inherit from this class.

If t is meant to be just any class, use `IEnumerable(Of T)` (capital T).

Comment: No, it's just an ASP.NET website.

Comment: What is t? A class? Or a generic parameter? In the latter case, try T. In the former case, t should be public.